# Missing data in Watson IoT Platform from device

Tags: watson-iot

I installed the WIoT installer

```
pi@raspberrypijps1 ~ $ service iot status
[ ok ] iot is running.
pi@raspberrypijps1 ~ $ service iot getdeviceid
Running in registered mode
#config
    org=faa9v
    type=iotsample-raspberrypi
    id=B827EB51C569
    auth-method=token
    auth-token=......
#end of config file
```

Added the device on the WIoT platform. However, the device data for B827EB51C569 is not showing up.

**Browse Device** results in **Connection Status Disconnected**.

Comment: It looks that the organization id (org in th configuration file) is not correct. The orgID is 6 chars long and the auth-method should be:

auth-method=use-token-auth

Are you following any tutorial? I might think the information in there needs to be updated.

Comment: thx, doublechecked the tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/raspberry-pi-4/, that worked

Comment: thanks for your update. I've asked for the tutorial to be changed.